# Как сделать в реакте такой-же футер?

Tags: html, css, reactjs, pagination, design

На этом сайте (https://jolybell.com/) мне понравился футер, который появляется, если пользователь сделал хотя-бы один скролл, но если пользователь находится в верхней точке страницы, то при выставлении любого разрешения, его не будет видно, а как только сделаешь скролл, он отображается, как это реализовать?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

там же нет никаких спецэффектов с футером, просто секции до него занимают высоту всего экрана, из-за чего они толкают вниз, вот тот самый css-код, благодаря которому до футера всегда надо скролить

```
.default-page {
    min-height: calc(100vh - 230px);
    min-height: calc(var(--vh, 1vh)*100 - 230px);
}
```